# If Kripacharya is an immortal and one of the chiranjeevi and also the kulguru of hastinapur, where was he during the snake sacrifice of Janamejaya?

Tags: mahabharata

go to http://sacred-texts.com/ and read about mahabharat. Where was he when during the sarpa satra of Janamejaya, when Vaisampayana was narrating the 1st narration of Mahabharat in which Kripacharya is also there, where was Kripacharya during the time of Sarpa Satra?